# Creating a link to an Activity with a TextView

Tags: android, textview, android-activity

I have an `Activity` called `MainActivity.java`, with an `activity_main.xml` file. But I don't know how to create a link that will launch another activity called `DirectionActivity`.  Below is a sample of my code.

strings.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
     <string name="app_name">EEMA</string>
     <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
     <string name="hello_world">The Emergency Evacuation Mobile App!</string>
     <string name="directions">\n\nTo view directions click here!</string>
     <string name="title_activity_direction">DirectionActivity</string>
     <string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>
</resources>
```

activity_main.xml textview

```
<TextView  android:id="@+id/txtView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="" 
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textColorLink="#FFFF00"
    android:textStyle="bold"
/>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainMenuActivity extends Activity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);

        String str = "Please click here to view Directions";
        TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView);
        txtView.setText(str);
        Linkify.addLinks(txtView, Linkify.ALL);     
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

DirectionActivity.java

```
public class DirectionActivity extends Activity {

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainMenuActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        // Create the text view    
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);    
        textView.setTextSize(40);    
        textView.setText(message);

        // Set the text view as the activity layout    
        setContentView(textView);       
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_direction);

        // Make sure we're running on Honeycomb or higher to use ActionBar APIs        
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {            
            // Show the Up button in the action bar.            
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);        
        }       
    }
}
```

So what is it I need to do to get the Please click here to view Directions to appear as a link that will open the DirectionActivity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to do two things. First, you want to have something happen upon the click of a `TextView`. Second, you want to launch a new `Activity`.

To accomplish the first thing, in your activity class' `onCreate` method, you want something like:

```
final TextView txtView = this.findViewById(R.id.txtView);
txtView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ...
    }
});
```

To then accomplish the second thing, if the `Activity` you want to launch is called `DirectionActivity`:

```
final TextView txtView = this.findViewById(R.id.txtView);
txtView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        MainMenuActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(MainMenuActivity.this, DirectionActivity.class));
    }
});
```

Comment: Do I need to worry about disposing of the listener for garbage collection?

Comment: When I add this code I get the error message "Multiple markers at this line
 - The constructor Intent(new View.OnClickListener(){}, Class<DirectionActivity>) is 
  undefined"

Comment: Oops, fixing code. Try it now. The problem was I was using `this` instead of `MainMenuActivity.this`.

Comment: Now I am getting The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}

Comment: Oops, same problem but `MainMenuActivity.this.startActivity`. Will update code. Sorry, didn't run it on Android since I'm not set up at the moment to do so.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26056/discussion-between-yarian-and-mark-basler)